# Transferring text messages with upgrade from iPhone 4 to iPhone 5

Tags: iphone

My text messages did not transfer. Is there a way to get them yet? They are still on the old phone.

Comment: Can you erase the new phone and do a back up / restore from the old phone?

Comment: Possibly, but would I lose any information in the process?

Comment: You would lose everything on the new phone that's not synced elsewhere. Apps, contacts, music, books - all that can sync - but you'd lose the new messages since they don't get mixed (you can't combine parts of two back up events or devices).

Answer (score 4):

I would get a program like [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) and just archive both device's SMS/Voicemail/call records. Unless the new phone is really new and you don't mind losing the new texts to restore a backup of all the texts from the old, there's not a way to inject or combine both stores of text messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first back up the old iphone 4, then restore the new iphone 5 to this backup, which contains your messages.To prevent from losing any data that only exist on your new iphone 5 but not on the old one, you should save these data before you do the backup and restore, because this will revert all settings and datas.