# Cannot synch iMessages from old iPhone to new activated iPhone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, messages

It seems that my text/iMessages from old iPhone is not synching with my new iPhone.  Is there anything special that needs to be done for the messages to synch?  Everything else is synched.

Answer (score 1):

iMessage history only syncs a limited window. If you need to get all of the messages, backup the old phone to iCloud or iTunes, wipe the new phone and then restore the backup.

- [Transferring text messages with upgrade from iPhone 4 to iPhone 5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90441/transferring-text-messages-with-upgrade-from-iphone-4-to-iphone-5)